# my accessor not working in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-5.5, accessor

I have a model that have one accessor inside it

```
class Test extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'subject','date',
   ];


    public function getSubjectAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }
}
```

When I call model, accessor does not work
I read all documents and Q&A , but ... 
My Laravel version in 5.5

----- edit

In the model I have a method for fetch data

```
public function get_specific_subject($id){
    $subject = DB::table("subjects")
        ->where("id", "=", $id)
        ->first();

    return $subject;
}
```

And I am calling this method in my controller by bellow code

```
    $subject = new Test();
    $subject = $subject->get_specific_subject($subject_id);
    dd($subject);
```

Comment: How are you calling your model and how are you trying to use this function outside the class? Show some more code.

Comment: Paste your code snippet and show how you call this method.

Comment: I've edited my post

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra letter 's' in the name of methods,  Your field name is subject not subjects -

tyy -

```
public function getSubjectAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }
```

Comment: The "s" was just a copy pasting bug !! I've edited my question

Comment: Request you to accept the previous answer. And open another thread for this problem. Will surely answer you.

Answer (score 0):

try this : you have written `getSubjectsAttribute` instead of `getSubjectAttribute`

```
 public function getSubjectAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }
```

Comment: The "s" was just a copy pasting bug !! I've edited my question